# More efficient way to sum values with critieria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each unique value of A (say S1, S2, S3 in below table), target is to get a new column D, if C is False then D is 0, if C is True then D is sum of B between False and True grouped by A.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['S1', 10, False], ['S1', 10, True],
    ['S2', 20, False], ['S2', 10, False], ['S2', 10, True],
    ['S2', 100, False], ['S2', 100, True],
    ['S3', 200, False], ['S3', 100, False], ['S3', 100, True]],
    columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)
    A    B      C
0  S1   10  False
1  S1   10   True
2  S2   20  False
3  S2   10  False
4  S2   10   True
5  S2  100  False
6  S2  100   True
7  S3  200  False
8  S3  100  False
9  S3  100   True
```

This can be achieved with loop as below:

```
codes = df.A.unique()
dfs = []
for code in codes:
    subdf = df[df.A == code].reset_index()
    slices = subdf[subdf.C].index
    slices = slices.insert(0, -1)
    for i in range(len(slices) - 1):
        tempdf = subdf.loc[slices[i]+1: slices[i+1]].copy()
        tempdf['D'] = np.where(tempdf.C, tempdf.groupby('A').B.sum(), 0)
        dfs.append(tempdf)
df_with_d = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()
print(df_with_d[list('ABCD')])
    A    B      C    D
0  S1   10  False    0
1  S1   10   True   20
2  S2   20  False    0
3  S2   10  False    0
4  S2   10   True   40
5  S2  100  False    0
6  S2  100   True  200
7  S3  200  False    0
8  S3  100  False    0
9  S3  100   True  400
```

But I believe there's more efficient and pandas way, need your help.

Already tried below but without luck:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df.C, df.groupby('A')['B'].cumsum(), 0)
print(df)
    A    B      C    D
0  S1   10  False    0
1  S1   10   True   20
2  S2   20  False    0
3  S2   10  False    0
4  S2   10   True   40
5  S2  100  False    0
6  S2  100   True  240
7  S3  200  False    0
8  S3  100  False    0
9  S3  100   True  400
```

Also tried this but still without luck:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df.C, df.groupby(df.C.eq(False).cumsum()).B.cumsum(), 0)
print(df)
    A    B      C    D
0  S1   10  False    0
1  S1   10   True   20
2  S2   20  False    0
3  S2   10  False    0
4  S2   10   True   20
5  S2  100  False    0
6  S2  100   True  200
7  S3  200  False    0
8  S3  100  False    0
9  S3  100   True  200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple and efficient way to do it:

```
df['temp'] = df['C'].shift(fill_value=False).cumsum()
df['D'] = np.where(df.C,df.groupby(['A','temp'])['B'].cumsum(),0)

df.drop('temp',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    A    B      C    D
0  S1   10  False    0
1  S1   10   True   20
2  S2   20  False    0
3  S2   10  False    0
4  S2   10   True   40
5  S2  100  False    0
6  S2  100   True  200
7  S3  200  False    0
8  S3  100  False    0
9  S3  100   True  400
```